# Synology NAS disk crashed flag

Tags: linux, raid, nas, lvm, synology

Trying to understand and find where and how the "crashed" status of a disk is stored/calculated. I've had a little poke around in ssh with some common commands people use (mdadm, mount, fdisk. I know the disk is fine, it's basically brand new, and smart is fine, part of a 4 disk shr  1 array. I suspect it's just not derived in the array properly. Looking to see if there's some way I retest it or define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, the disk "Crashed" state was being generated from the fact that the system, swap & only 1 of the 3 data partitions where actually being detected as present in cat /proc/mdstat even though the disk was fine, and the partitions where actually there. And once the where added back into their corresponding /dev/mdX devices with mdadm the disk status switched to "Normal" in synology.